# Squid loses route on restart

Tags: networking, routing, squid

Every time we restart squid I loose a few routes and have to restore from snapshot. is there a way to make sure our routs stay saved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add route in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Example

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
       address 10.0.0.21
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.0.0.1
       up ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
       down ip route del 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

Note `up ip ...` and `down ip ...`

This will secure that will route go up when interface `eth0` go up, or `down` when `eth0` go down.

Edit 1

Also on this way you can add `eth1:1` int an route for that int ...

```
auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
       address 10.0.0.21
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.0.0.1
       up ip addr add 10.0.1.21/24 dev eth1 label eth1:1
       down ip addr del 10.0.1.21/24 dev eth1 label eth1:1
       up ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1:1 metric 20
       down ip route del 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1:1 metric 20
```

If you need more help comment answer